# How to get path of a specific folder inside solution

Tags: c#

I want to get the path of a specific folder inside the solution.

Ive tried to find answers on stack overflow, but i guess my concentration is already near the end and i cant find a real usefull answer.

**Here is the folder i want (KeePassFiles):**

[image]

I had those 2 files on the desktop before and reading them worked. But now i have to add those files into one of the solution folder and i only want to get the path for that.
It should work for different users who download that project.

My code right now for the desktop solution is:

```
            string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var dbpath = @$"{desktopPath}\KeePassDatabase\Database.kdbx";
            var keypath = @$"{desktopPath}\KeePassDatabase\Database.key";
```

Now it should be something like:

```
            string solutionKPPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(path for solution);
            var dbpath = @$"{solutionKPPath}\KeePassFiles\Database.kdbx";
            var keypath = @$"{solutionKPPath}\KeePassFiles\Database.key";
```

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` maybe?

Comment: What is the Build Action for those files? [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019) depending on this the files copied to the output or included in the dll.

Comment: @DanielW. those files are needed for the selenium automation test. We use the nuget package for "KeePass" which is a password manager. And with those 2 files we access that password database in KeePass. The one is the database, the other one is the key file.

Comment: @Charlieface Hm doesnt work. The folder i need is at:
Solution 'Azkaban' - Tests - Shared - KeePassFiles
Id like to get the path for the folder "Shared". But the path shouldnt start with 'C:\xx\...', it should directly call it from inside the solution

Comment: I just don't get why you would want the solution folder: normally you compile the application, and copy any extra files directly to the build output location (Build Action: Copy), which is `Environment.CurrentDirectory` at runtime. The point is that you want to be able to run the application away from VS, so you should copy all necessary files

Comment: So how are you supposed to know the location of the downloaded files on someone else's computer...? You can't. Use relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Environment.CurrentDirectory will return the Debug directory or the Release directory depending on your run configuration. As far as I know, there is no easy way to get a specific folder or file in your solution. The best solution I could think of is using something like the following to get the solution directory:

```
public static DirectoryInfo TryGetSolutionDirectoryInfo(string currentPath = null)
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(
            currentPath ?? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        while (directory != null && !directory.GetFiles("*.sln").Any())
        {
            directory = directory.Parent;
        }
        return directory;
    }
```

And then use that path to dig into your folders and find the specific file you're looking for using something like Path.Combine(...).

In your case, don't pass any parameters to this method if you want it to retrieve the Debug/Release directory and search up from there

Edit: Note that this will actually not work for production since there will be no .sln file to find. As suggested by the comments on your question, you should configure your project to copy the necessary files into the output folder and therefore Environment.CurrentDirectory will do the trick

Comment: "Unfortunately"? There is no concept of a solution or project at runtime so this path should not matter and certainly not be used. What will happen when  you install the compiled app on another machine where there is no source code...?

Comment: Yes, you're right, and I thought I made that clear in my edit. When I said unfortunately, I just meant that there is no way for him to simply get the solution folder as he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not get the files from the project source, you should copy them to the output during build and then get them from output location.

I would recommend to use *"Copy to Output directory= Copy Allways"* and than identify the *"Execution Path"* by use of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` or `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`

If you using Unit Test, especially MS UnitTests it may be necessary to use `[DeploymentItem(@"\Shared\Keepassfiles\Database.kdbx")]